Does Spark really leverage parquet encoding/compression in mem?
I have multiple question about how spark handles data internally.
First Topic :  In Mem data compression;
I heard in multiple sources i can't find anymore ( Medium, Youtube; Data with Zack)  that parquet encoding was taken into account by spark. ( in my case pyspark )  and that unwanted shuffeling can remove it.
But i cannot find any piece of official documentation that specifies it.
Especially when i do a caching of the data, it goes from 300Mb to 2Gb so i don't really see any encoding or compression kept ?
Second topic: Caching;
About caching, here is what they say in official Pyspark doc;
     -->They say in python, records are always serialized. ( as mentioned below ) 


""" .. note:: The following four storage level constants are
deprecated in 2.0, since the records
will always be serialized in Python.
""" StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER = StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY """.. note::
Deprecated in 2.0, use StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY instead."""
StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2 = StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_2 """..
note:: Deprecated in 2.0, use StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_2
instead.""" StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER =
StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK """.. note:: Deprecated in 2.0, use
StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK instead."""
StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2 = StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2
""".. note:: Deprecated in 2.0, use StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2
instead."""

--> However, in spark UI, the cached Dataframes are always marked as "DESERIALIZED" 

even if
df.cache()
df.storageLevel

returns
StorageLevel(True,True,False,True,1). 

The fourth boolean being used for flagging serialization is at "True".
EDIT : regarding topic 2

the StorageLevel definition is :
class pyspark.StorageLevel(useDisk: bool, useMemory: bool, useOffHeap: bool, deserialized: bool, replication: int = 1)[source]
the 4rth bool is for Flagging DESERIALIZATION and not the opposite.
and cache() has default value of DISK_MEM_DESER which explains all.
i got confused because they were saying that the storage levels were automatically SER. the difference being that the default was not DISK_MEM but DISK_MEM_DESER

the update explains why it's DESERIALIZED in spark ui but not if the spark takes leverage of parquet encoding.
Thanks for your help.
